# How to prevent connected nodes from being 'foregrounded' on a node's drag event

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js to draw a graph. I give the library a graph object and run the dagre layout for the graph.  Then I manually position cytoscape node elements, which act as buttons, on each graph node.  This lays out fine.  Image is attached below.

However, when I drag a node around, the connected graph nodes become 'foregrounded' and are drawn on top of the 'buttons' that I have positioned on top of each node.

I have tried to manually set the z-indexes of each of these 'button' nodes to a very high value (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and also setting the z-index of the connected graph nodes to a very low value, but the graph nodes still clip through and are drawn on top of the 'button' nodes for the duration of the drag.

How can I prevent the nodes graph nodes from overlapping/being drawn on top of the nodes that I manually placed?

How it should look:
[image]

> The red/green/black bars and arrows are nodes that are drawn on top of the base graph node

How it looks on drag - not desired:
[image]

> The connected nodes (violet colored nodes) are covering the 'button' nodes